# How to print last element of sub array in a 2d array ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby and i want to print the last element in a sub array from a 2d array. I've tried using an each iterator but it gave me an error: "no implicit conversion of Array into Integer (TypeError)"

```
pairs = [['name', 'sam'], ['age', '56'], ['height', '179']]

pairs.each{ |x| puts pairs[x][1] }
```

Preferred output:
sam
56
179

Any suggestions will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Within the `each` block, `x` refers to a single sub-array at a time, e.g. for the first iteration you can think of `x = ['name', 'sam']`. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there
`pairs.each { |x| puts x[1] }`